# Routing elasticsearch field in terraform

Tags: elasticsearch, apache-kafka, terraform, apache-kafka-connect

For example in logstash I have next config in output

```
 if [@metadata][kafka][topic] == "cash-box-dynamic" {
    elasticsearch {
            hosts => ["elasticsearch:9200"]
            index => "cash-boxes"
            document_id => "dynamic_%{[joinField][parent]}"
            routing => "%{[joinField][parent]}"
            template => "/local/template/backend_logstash_cash_boxes_template.json"
            template_name => "cash-box"
            manage_template => true
            template_overwrite => true
        }
    }
```

And data in my index need to looks like this

```
{
        "_index" : "cash-box-dynamic",
        "_type" : "_doc",
        "_id" : "dynamic_1601260015",
        "_score" : 0.6931471,
        "_routing" : "1601260015",
        "_source" : {
          "cashRegisterFactoryNumber": "100",
          "deviceFactoryNumber": "200",
          "timeDelta" : 330,
          "joinField" : {
            "name" : "dynamic",
            "parent" : "1601260015"
          },
          "status" : "REGISTRATION",
        }
}
```

I depreceted logstash and use kafka stream + elasticsearch sink connector + terraform (for rest api in kafka-connector and elasticsearch).

I use to this kafka connect image https://hub.docker.com/layers/confluentinc/cp-kafka-connect/5.4.10/images/sha256-e09d5b21f8717198f9873fd42b44c19881c7d16237d099f8d6db5256b6b6db3c?context=explore

And this elasticsearch sink connector [enter link description here](https://www.confluent.io/hub/confluentinc/kafka-connect-elasticsearch) ver. 14.0.2

Sink connector read from topics

```
"cash-box-dynamic", "cash-box-aggregate"
```

And put data from topics into eponymous indexes by terraform

```
resource "kafka-connect_connector" "cash_box_dynamic" {
  name = "cash_box_dynamic"
  config = {
    "connector.class"                                 = "io.confluent.connect.elasticsearch.ElasticsearchSinkConnector"
    "tasks.max"                                       = var.cash_box_dynamic_tasks_max
    "topics"                                          = "cash-box-dynamic"
    "key.ignore"                                      = "false"
    "schema.ignore"                                   = "true"
    "connection.url"                                  = var.elasticsearch_url
    "type.name"                                       = "_doc"
    "name"                                            = "cash_box_dynamic"
    "key.converter"                                   = "org.apache.kafka.connect.storage.StringConverter"
    "value.converter"                                 = "org.apache.kafka.connect.json.JsonConverter"
    "value.converter.schemas.enable"                  = "false"
    "flush.synchronously"                             = "true"
  }
}
```

I configured terraform index template for aliases cash-boxes like this

```
resource "elasticstack_elasticsearch_index_template" "cash_boxes_backend" {
  name     = "cash-boxes-backend"
  priority = 10

  index_patterns = ["cash-box-dynamic", "cash-box-aggregate"]

  template {
    settings = jsonencode({
      number_of_shards       = "1"
    })
    alias {
      name = "cash-boxes"
    }
    mappings = file("/app/terraform-module-gs-connectors/files/backend_logstash_cash_boxes_template.json")
  }
  version = 1
}
```

and have next index pattern for index alias cash-boxes
**backend_logstash_cash_boxes_template.json**

```
{
  "properties": {
    "cashRegisterFactoryNumber": {
      "type": "keyword"
    },
    "deviceFactoryNumber": {
      "type": "keyword"
    },
    "status": {
      "type": "keyword"
    },
    "timeDelta": {
      "type": "long"
    },
    "joinField": {
      "type": "join",
      "relations": {
        "static": "dynamic"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

The problem is that according to documentation https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/parent-join.html
I have to use in join field routing field (important that it's need to be custom like in the logstash config). But how I can do this in the terraform or maybe in elasticsearch sink connector?

Comment: So what you want needs to happen in the JSON file?

Comment: I want to add routing field, because when this data put in the index, I have next Caused by: ElasticsearchException[Elasticsearch exception [type=illegal_argument_exception, reason=[routing] is missing for join field [joinField]]]
at org.elasticsearch.ElasticsearchException.innerFromXContent(ElasticsearchException.java:491)
at org.elasticsearch.ElasticsearchException.fromXContent(ElasticsearchException.java:402)
at org.elasticsearch.ElasticsearchException.innerFromXContent(ElasticsearchException.java:432)

Comment: My question is still the same: does it have to be inside the `backend_logstash_cash_boxes_template.json` JSON file or you would expect it in a resource or somewhere else?

Comment: The error seems self explanatory, but that's not anything that terraform or connect has any control over over. You need to explicitly edit that json mappings file